# Serilog .NET CORE 5 Web API - Show In Docker Logs

Tags: docker, serilog, .net-5

I have an extremely simple web api created with .NET Core 5 which is set to host in a linux Docker container. All I want to do is have my console output go into the Docker logs, like it has in the past versions of .NET Core.

Here is my Main method in Program.cs

```
var LOG_EVENT_LEVEL = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOG_EVENT_LEVEL");
var logEventLevel = LOG_EVENT_LEVEL != null
    ? Enum.Parse<LogEventLevel>(LOG_EVENT_LEVEL)
    : LogEventLevel.Information;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console(logEventLevel)
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Information("START");
```

I would think that the output "START" should be shown in my Docker logs, but it isn't. I see them in the debug window of VS as expected. Has something changed in .NET Core 5?

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this question. I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days now. My containerized .NET Core app also stopped sending logs to Docker, which kills my entire logging system (my setup forwards Docker logs to Seq). Just like you, I can still see the logs in the debug window, but not Docker. Unlike you, I am still on .NET Core 3.1, so I don't think it's related to the .NET Core 5 upgrade. The only thing I changed before my logs stopped working was an automatic Docker Desktop update from 3.0.0 to 3.0.4. I'm guessing that the update is the culprit, but I do not know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out Visual Studio highjacks the standard output of the container while debugging. If you manually start the container on your machine, you will see the output in the logs as normal.